# Clean git commit history

Tags: git

I do have a problem with my commit history. Well, it isn't actually a problem, since it's not affecting a problem, it's more a visual problem. Basically I'm working on a CakePHP project and I made quite a mess trying to add CakePHP as submodule, but then I gave up. The problem is that my history now looks like this (on Tower):

[image: Screenshot from Tower]

As you can see, the line stops and starts again, and before there's all the CakePHP history, the one of its git repository. What should I do to remove it all?! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you accidentally pulled CakePHP into your project directly instead of adding it as a submodule. The simplest thing to do may be to delete the entire repo and start over (or create a new repo and only pull the master branch from your existing one). You could also try deleting all the refs left behind by the CakePHP fetch, but that's going to be some work, and it'll leave the objects in your repo for a few months, and it sounds like this is a new project anyway so just pulling the commits you care about into a fresh repo is likely to be simpler.

To create a new repo that just contains the master branch of your existing one, something like the following should work:

```
mkdir newRepo
cd newRepo
git init
git fetch ../oldRepo/.git master:temp
git reset --hard temp
git branch -d temp
```

This will only fetch the `master` branch and nothing else. The bit with `temp` is because git will otherwise refuse to fetch into the HEAD of a non-bare repo.

In any case, once you have a fresh repo, you should be able to just use

```
git submodule add git://url/for/CakePHP.git path/to/submodule
```

to add the submodule.

Comment: Yeah I think I'll do this or, since the commits don't appear on my repo online, I'll just checkout that one, so I'll preserve the current commits without those! Thanks for the tip! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use [`git rebase -i`](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html) to enter interactive rebase mode, where you can pick which commits you want to keep, which you want to merge (`squash`) and which to completely remove (so the changes applied by that commit are removed from the repo). However you should do this only if you didn't already share your history. If the history is changed and someone with the old history tries to pull/merge with the new one it will give some very severe merge conflicts, since git won't detect any connection between the histories.

Comment: The problem is that those commits don't appear in `git rebase -i`! I already tried. :(

Comment: @Entropy: In that case you might want to tell us a bit more about which commits you want to remove and what you have already tried (e.g. how exactly did you call `git rebase -i`)